# Relationships between Spring, Hibernate, JDBC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc

I just start reading Sun's JDBC tutorial. I installed MySQL Connector/J and was just skimming through its menu, then came across this statement:

"Although JDBC is useful by itself, we would hope that if you are not familiar with JDBC that after reading the first few sections of this
manual, that you would avoid using naked JDBC for all but the most trivial problems and consider using one of the popular persistence
frameworks such as Hibernate, Spring's JDBC templates or Ibatis SQL Maps to do the majority of repetitive work and heavier lifting that is sometimes required with JDBC"

So what are the relationships between Spring, Hibernate, JDBC? What does the statement mean by saying "avoid using naked JDBC"?

Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723228/which-are-the-differences-similarities-between-hibernate-and-other-frameworks-or

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use Hibernate, Spring's JDBC templates or Ibatis SQL Maps, you're still using JDBC, but you don't have to deal with it directly.  They're doing it for you, and to a degree, insulate you from some difficulties in the use of JDBC.

[Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) is an [object-relational-mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) framework.

[MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/), formerly known as iBatis, is a data mapping framework.

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) is a wide-ranging set of web framework components, and includes templating subsystems that allow integration with JDBC, Hibernate, or iBatis and abstract away some of the details of dealing with any of them.

You should indeed learn JDBC, but also (eventually) learn some of these others and try to avoid using JDBC directly for anything very complex.

These ideas are also (especially Hibernate) closely related to the [Java Persistence API (JPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), which is also certainly worth learning.

You might also want to look at [Java Data Objects (JDO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects).

Don't try to learn it all at once, though.

Starting with JDBC is a good idea.  Staying with it is not.

Comment: *"Starting with JDBC is a good idea. Staying with it is not."* +1 for that (and the rest also)

Comment: Thanks. Love your answer because you also pointed out the learning direction apart from information.

Answer (score 4):

Alphabets `>` Words `>` Sentences.

That is how we learn (natural) language.

Similarly, I see:

JDBC API `>` JDBC API with Connection Pooling `>` Spring JDBC Template `>` ORM/JPA/JDO

Answer (score 2):

"avoid using naked JDBC" - Don't use the JDBC API directly.

[Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) - A database persistence framework. It lets you store Java objects in databases. Pretty nifty.

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) - It's actually a web development framework. The JDBC templates are an abstraction to JDBC, I think.

Comment: Spring is more than a  "web development framework" in 2016 ( a comment six years after I posted the question, hope you don't mind) :P